# Log message not displaying on console

Tags: python-3.x, logging, console

Below is the code I am trying to run. But the log message is not getting displayed on the console. I am running code on pycharm with Python3.8

```
import sys
import logging

ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
my_format = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(my_format)

LOGGER = logger.getLogger('myLogger')
LOGGER.addHandler(ch)
LOGGER.info('This message should get displayed on the console.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import sys
import logging

ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
my_format = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(my_format)

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.addHandler(ch)
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO) # Look at this.
LOGGER.info('This message should get displayed on the console.')
```

Comment: I thought the loglevel should be as per the handler. But that is not the case I guess. 
Thanks @script0